# Why does my website not load when I update my jQuery version?

Tags: jquery

The version I used initially was 1.12.4
It's at the end of my index.html file
When I change it to 3.2.1 (the latest version), my webpage doesn't loads indefinitely.
Both files are in my file folder

Comment: Check console for errors... jquery3 is not backward compatible with jquery1, so it will probably wont work.

Comment: @Dekel thanks! I did that and found a single error, that Bootstrap's Javascript requires version 1.9 or higher, but lower than 3. But why version 1.12.4 works beats me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe reasons below:

- jQuery3.2.1 don't support ie6-8
- jQuery3.2.1 remove a lot of grammar while you use them in jQuery1.12

If you need to support older browsers like IE6-8,Opera 12.1x or safari 5.1+,use jQuery1.12